# supuesto ")" perdido en ejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

Pues tengo el problema de que estoy con un CRUD de mongodb y node js pero el problema viene con ejs, porque ando creando el cuerpo y tengo esto:

```
<%= async for(var i = 0; i < allReports.report.length; i++) {%>
            <tr>
              <th><%= await allReports.report[i] %></th>
              <%= } %>
               <%= async for(var i = 0; i < allReports.name.length; i++) {%>
              <th><%= await allReports.name[i] %></th>
            </tr>
            <%= } %>
```

Lo que quiero es mostrar los datos de mi db en el código, pero no puedo saber si se muestran porque cuando compilo y lo mieo salta este error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\DIRECTORIO\views\reports.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
```

Hice caso al error y probé ejs-lint pero persiste, intenté el `async: true` pero nada, no sé si alguien por aquí tenga una respuesta?

Comment: En las líneas donde inicias y cierras los bucles, debes usar `<% async for(...) {%>` (sin el símbolo de igualdad). Sólo en las líneas de inicio y cierre de tus ciclos `for`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Lo intenté, pero sigue sin funcionar, por si acaso me puedes mandar código por si es que lo estoy haciendo mal??

Answer (score 0):

Así como dijo Mauricio, en ejs sólo debes poner la etiqueta <%= %> cuando quieres que algo se muestre en la web.
Si tienes por ejemplo la expresión: `my text is: ${myText}` sí que quieres imprimirla.
Sin embargo, cuando estas haciendo javascript para tratar datos (declarando funciones, variables, haciendo if y for) la etiqueta correcta es <% %>, que no escribirá nada en la web.
A parte de esto no he encontrado ningún error en tu código más allá de que si estas ejecutando awaits en ejs deberías renderizarlo de forma asíncrona:

- https://ejs.co/
  Esta es la wiki de ejs, haz ctrl + F y busca async. Deberías encontrar los datos necesarios.